# which html tag that contains picture has best performance?

Tags: html, performance

I want to build a 10 x 10 thumbs of pictures in html page. (aspx)

there is a lot of options how to do it.

`my question is :`  which html **tag**( which will contain the picture - is being rendered the **most** fastest !!

p.s.:

a) the picture is not pressable :

b) I dont have the ability to create sprite image.

options :

1) div with background image

2) img tag

3) maybe other option ?

Comment: What did you try? What alternatives did you test? What do you mean by 'performance'?

Comment: @Erno Ive written that already : look at the options

Comment: What do you mean render fastest? This is only determined by the browser and how fast it can load the image.

Comment: I read the question, but it doesn't show a problem. Did you notice a difference in performance?

Comment: @oded I mean that if a browser see div with background-image to be renedered vs img to be rendered ( for the same picture)  - which one will be rendered fastest ( same browser)

Comment: Same speed for the image, assuming the browser encounters and loads the image at the same time.

Comment: I can't help but think you are optimizing for the wrong thing. With 100 separate thumbnails loading, the fact that a browser by default will only download 4 at a time, rendering time (once the image has been transmitted over the Internet) is negligible.

Comment: @oded I think the default is 2 connections a t the time( configurable by reg hack) ....I was asked(this abstract questions) with the fact that the images are already in my cache. so the only thing is to render to the right container... that was my question.. thanks :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I believe it is 4-10 depending on browser, but regardless. I would update the question with the details of expecting the images to already be cached and you simply want the "right container".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a *tabular* format, you should use a table.

To avoid reflows use the width and height attributes for the rows and columns to ensure the browser renders the container table correctly to begin with. This also means setting width and height on the `img` elements.

So, use a table with `img` elements in each cell.

Comment: doesnt table elements increase the viewsource of the page ? I personally intend not to use tables  ( as far as i can) - Also  - with a table wont it be better to use backgroundImage for the TD ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Tables are perfectly fine for a tabular format. They will not add much more markup than embedded divs would. As for using a background image - I don't really think so (though you may want to test).

Comment: Really, if you are only showing 10 images and not doing anything more with them it doesn't really matter how you do it, the performance difference won't be noticeable.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon - 10x10 == 100

Answer (score 2):

Opinion:

From my experience `background images` tend to load faster, altough images with height and width specifed can load faster, but I don't think you have that option. I also know you don't have the option for sprites, which are actually good because the image is loaded once.

It depends a lot on how big the files are, but I'd go with `img tags` for `simplicity and flexibility`.

Answer (score 0):

The best performace all around would be to use a sprite, i.e. combine all the images in one [(there are online tools to do that)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sprite%20generator),  then use css to show only the section that you need.

Loading images in the background renders faster than using an image element, but the difference would hardly be noticeable in this case. Also semantically it sounds like image elements would make more sense - if you turn off images then the page wouldn't make sense, they are not just decorative elements.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you mean the bit about stripes, not sprites?

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough, than in your simple case it really makes no difference if you use img nodes or not performance wise but semantically I'd go for img